# What are some methods of proving undefinability results? (Reference)

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic

I'm trying to prove some results regarding undefinability of functions from the natural numbers in certain structures, but besides texts on elemental logic and number theory, i haven't found anything exclusive to undefinability results. Can you recommend me certain papers regarding the subject, please?